# How to make divider part of each item in listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, divider

I wanted to change the **divider height** dynamically. From whatever I have searched it seems that it is possible through setting divider as part of each item in `ListView`. But I am not very clear with this.

So, can someone be more specific as how can one make the **divider** as part of item in `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this would be to include the divider at the bottom of each row. Now you have to set the height of the divider view in your [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method in your listadapter depending of the item you are showing at the moment.

Comment: I didn't get you how can one add divider at the bottom of each row. I have one xml file row.xml. How to add divider in this row.xml and change its height at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Atlast I managed to do it with your suggestion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do this? I'm still a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is better than explaining by picture. Here I found a screenshot from web. I made some mark on it.

This is what you want to achieve.
[image]

You can make the divider as one of the items.
[image]

Also, you can make the divider as a part of an item.
[image]

Neither of the 2 solutions uses real divider provided by `ListView`. It should be set 0 height. Sounds silly but it does effective.

Answer (score -1):

You could set android:footerDividersEnabled to false and add dividers in your adapter.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know how to add dividers from adapter. If you have some idea then please let me know.

Comment: I have managed to do it. Thanks a lot to everyone for helping me out in this.

Answer (score -1):

In your ListActivity call:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setDivider(divider);
```

where divider is a Drawable object which you can define or write in your code as you need to.

You can also call:

```
lv.setDividerHeight(2);
```

To change the height

Comment: Do I need to write this code in getView method of adapter? I am not using ListActivity for listview.

Comment: This will not allow you to have divider with a different height.

Comment: @sunil, no, this code goes in your Activity (you're using a ListActivity, right?), probably onCreate(). If you need different heights per row, then Janusz is right, in this case you'll have to add the divider to each row and change height programmatically in adapter's getView()